# Crear "swtich label"

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo 5 labels diferentes. Necesito que al hacer click en cada una se dispare una funcion que reciba como parametro el texto de la label. Tengo algo asi:

```
    <div>
      <ion-text
        class="ux-font-lato ux-fweight-semibold ux-fsize-14"
        color="uxsemidark"
      >
        24 horas
      </ion-text>
    </div>
    <div>
      <ion-text
        class="ux-font-lato ux-fweight-semibold ux-fsize-14"
        color="uxsemidark"
      >
        7 días
      </ion-text>
    </div>
    <div>
      <ion-text
        class="ux-font-lato ux-fweight-semibold ux-fsize-14"
        color="uxsemidark"
      >
        30 días
      </ion-text>
    </div>
    <div>
      <ion-text
        class="ux-font-lato ux-fweight-semibold ux-fsize-14"
        color="uxsemidark"
      >
        90 días
      </ion-text>
    </div>
    <div>
      <ion-text
        class="ux-font-lato ux-fweight-semibold ux-fsize-14"
        color="uxsemidark"
      >
        Todo
      </ion-text>
    </div>
```

Y la funcion es simple:

```
function imprimir(label) {
  alert(label)
}
```

Gracias!

Comment: ¿Qué es tener 5 labels diferentes? ¿Cada "label" es una etiqueta `<ion-text>`? ¿Quieres hacerlo usando el marco de trabajo Ionic o prefieres javascript puro?

Comment: Si, exactamente.

Comment: Hecho. Espero que la respuesta sea de tu agrado. Si no funciona o tienes dudas déjame un comentario en ella.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta con agregar a cada elemento un evento `click` mediante [`addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) y, posteriormente, pasar a tu función el contenido ([`innerText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText)) del elemento pulsado:

```js
/* Tu función */
function imprimir(label) {
  alert(label)
}

/* Buscamos los elementos */
document.querySelectorAll('ion-text').forEach(elemento => {
  /* A cada elemento le agregamos un evento al hacer clic */
  elemento.addEventListener('click', evento => {
    /* Que llamará a tu función con el contenido en texto del elemento */
    imprimir(evento.target.innerText); /* Usando el evento */
    imprimir(elemento.innerText); /* Usando el elemento iterado */
  })
});
```

```css
/* Cambiamos un poco la apariencia de cada elemento */
ion-text {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div><ion-text>24 horas</ion-text></div>
<div><ion-text>7 días</ion-text></div>
<div><ion-text>30 días</ion-text></div>
<div><ion-text>90 días</ion-text></div>
<div><ion-text>Todo</ion-text></div>
```

Comment: Excelente, muchas gracias!